# How can I test JSch scp command in an integration test?

Tags: spring-boot, docker, jsch, testcontainers

I have taken this file http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/ScpTo.java.htm and I made a Spring Boot application that SCPs a file to a remote host. However, I am having trouble thinking about how to test this to ensure that it can send a file to a remote server.

I have created unit tests for each of the components I made, but I am having trouble thinking of how to create an integration test for this application with everything wired as a spring boot application that will test SCPing to a remote host but be self contained for a CI build.

One idea I had was using [testcontainers](https://www.testcontainers.org) and Spring boot, but there are a couple of things that I need to verify.

1. What would I put in the dockerfile?
2. And what kind of wait strategy would I use given that I am not exposing an HTTP port in the docket image for server connectivity?
3. Will SCP work between host and docker container given that docker has docker-cp?

My codebase can be found [here](https://github.com/teamfam2014/spring-scp).

Comment: We are having test containers tests at https://github.com/mwiede/jsch/blob/master/src/test/java/com/jcraft/jsch/AlgorithmsIT.java

Comment: Thanks Matthias. Your code did help quite a bit with helping me model a working solution!

Comment: @JCB can you share some examples ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can probably try using https://hub.docker.com/r/rastasheep/ubuntu-sshd
2. I think you don't have to specify a Wait strategy in your case.
3. You can obtain a host `container.getHost()` and work with it just like with a regular ssh server.